# Embed Flash (SWF) without JavaScript

Tags: html, flash, embed

How can I embed a Flash SWF file into an HTML page **without using JavaScript libraries**?

The Flash movie is an advertisement which will run on sites that don't have any JavaScript libraries available (like SWFObject). My only capability is to render a piece of HTML using `document.write`. I do not wish to add any external script tags (or `write` them for that matter).

The browser requirements are basically "all browsers":

- IE6+
- FF2+
- Chrome, Safari (WebKit)
- Recent version of Opera (not 100% required)

I do not care about validation. The only goal is to make it work reliably.

Answer (score 2):

use `<object> <object/>` &   The `OBJECT` tag is used by Internet Explorer on Windows,`EMBED` is used by Netscape Navigator (Macintosh and Windows) and Internet Explorer (Macintosh) tag like this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="myclip.swf"> 
    <param name="movie" value="myclip.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <!-- Sandwich the embed tag inside the object tag -->
    <embed src="myclip.swf" quality="high" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.swf"></object>
```

This will work on all browser, although I will suggest you to avoid using `<embed>` tag, as Firefox doesn't support that.
You can learn more about `<object>` tag from link below.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

Comment: Wrong. `<object>` tag alone is the one that is not supported in Firefox nor in Opera.

On a personal note, I would recommend you to start using good reference materials (such as [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) or [W3C Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-embed-element))

Answer (score 0):

I think it works quite reliably with an `<iframe>`.

```
<iframe src="myclip.swf" width="300" height="200" border="0" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ5Pk/ (Warning: Loud SWF)